# Testing connection quality in Teradata

Tags: jdbc, teradata

It is not recommended to use Fastload for small tables. But even for large tables  (200K-1M rows)  a simple prepared statements ( JDBC Multi-Statement requests ) approach can be 2-3 times faster than Fastload  IFF the connection is slow. So in order to speed up uploads one needs to know the connection speed

One way I can do this is to calculate how many seconds it takes to select smth :

`locking row for access 
 sel top 1 NULL from sometable` .

**Is there any better way ?**

*(PS: I have an application that uses either `fastload` or `regular mode` depending on the table's size. I also want to enable my application to give a preference to the regular mode if the connection is slow)*

Comment: Using TOP or SAMPLE with an unconstrained SELECT statement will cause the entire table to be spooled before the TOP or SAMPLE aggregate step has been applied. This can cause issues if submitted against a significantly large table in your environment. Are you referring to JDBC FastLoad vs. JDBC Multi-Statement requests or the standalone FastLoad/TPT utility?

Comment: I am referring to `JDBC FastLoad vs. JDBC Multi-Statement requests` . Also, I meant using `locking row for access sel top 1 null from sometable` . What can I do ?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM {Table};` - will not be a representative test of network throughput as there is no substantial data being returned to the application. It will be a test of the responsiveness of the database at a point in time. How are the users arriving at your application and the database? Are they uploading the data from their desktop or through another server in the data center?

Comment: They are uploading data from the desktop. Can I make a test `1 row upload` and see how long it takes ? Would that be more efficient ?

Comment: Not knowing the environment you are working in, but you could you just ping your server? That way you test actual network speeds instead of the myriad of reasons your Teradata server may be slow like I/O, CPU, or AWT availability.